sqlmock DB not meeting any mock expectations
I am trying to unit test GORM transactions in my code.  I am creating a transaction (*gorm.DB), calling Begin(), and then trying to Delete a record.  However, when I setup my DB and mock with sqlmock, I am getting an error ExpectedBegin => expecting database transaction Begin
Here is my code:
CreateTransaction(ctx context.Context) *gorm.DB
service.go
func (d *serviceImpl) deleteUnit(ctx context.Context, dbUnit *db.Unit) (err error) {
    tx := d.repo.CreateTransaction(ctx)
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
        }
    }()

    tx.WithContext(ctx).Begin()

    if err := tx.WithContext(ctx).Delete(&dbUnit).Error; err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    response, pErr := d.inventory.DeleteUnit(ctx, unit, location)
    if pErr != nil {
        d.logger.LogError(ctx, pErr.Error())
        tx.Rollback()
        return pErr
    }

    tx.Commit()

    return nil
}

service_test.go
func TestDeleteUnit(t *testing.T) {
    sut := svcUnderTest(t)
    defer sut.mockCtrl.Finish()

    dbUnit := db.Unit{
        ID:           "123",
        Field1:       "Field1",
        Field2:       "Field2",
    }

    deleteResponse := mih.Response{
        ID: "1",
    }

    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("an error was not expected: %v", err)
    }

    conn, _ := db.Conn(context.Background())
    gormDB, _ := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        Conn: conn,
    }), &gorm.Config{})

    sut.mockRepo.EXPECT().CreateTransaction(ctx).Return(gormDB)
    mock.ExpectBegin()

    query := regexp.QuoteMeta("DELETE FROM `units` WHERE id = ?")
    mock.ExpectExec(query).WithArgs(dbUnit.ID).WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(0, 0))
    sut.mockInventory.EXPECT().DeleteUnit(ctx, gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).Return(&deleteResponse, nil)
    mock.ExpectCommit()

    if mockerr := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); mockerr != nil {
        t.Errorf("not all expectations were met: %v", mockerr)
    }

    testerr := sut.svc.DeleteUnit(ctx, address)
    assert.NoError(t, testerr)
}

The errors I'm seeing are:
not all expectations were met: there is a remaining expectation which was not matched: ExpectedBegin => expecting database transaction Begin
and
missing call(s) to *mocks.MockService.DeleteUnit(is equal to context.Background (*context.emptyCtx), is anything, is anything)
It doesn't seem as though my gormDB object is getting used correctly.  I've looked at a lot of example code and cannot see what I'm doing differently.  Perhaps my query isn't correct?  But stepping through it seems to bomb out before I can even see the statement being built.
